# Oracle select data and update while limiting rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to select data and update the records selected. I am able to do this without row limitation but soon as I limit the rows I get an error "ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here". Below is code snippet that I am using.

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT
   someColumns
  FROM table
  Where Status = 'TODO'
  fetch first 1000 rows only  
)
SET status = 'Done',
Date = SYSTIMESTAMP
```

I have also tried to limit using Rownum but that gives error "ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view"

Does anyone know another way perhaps that I can select while limiting number of rows and updating the records in same statement in oracle?

Comment: The data returned by a [SQL] query has no order (unless the query contains an ORDER BY clause - which yours doesn't) so why is it important to only update the first 1000 rows? How do you know that you are updating only relevant rows? Or do you want to perform the update in chunks as you think it is more efficient?

Comment: Just write normal update statement, without a select.

Comment: Query will be run by another program based on other rules, and don't want to bring through 100K+ records so need to limit what is fetched each time while updating certain fields

Comment: Are you fetching or are you updating? You can't do both at the same time. If updating, just update with a normal update statement. If fetching, use a normal select statement.

Comment: If this is a queue table that you need to fetch some records from and update to show they have been fetched, you are far better off coming back later and updating them by specific key to show that they have been fully/successfully processed, not that they have been fetched. If you have a race condition between threads all polling the table, update first with a agent identifier and a current date/timestamp , then select the rows marked by that agent and date. You can later use this to re-queue rows that were not successfully processed by having them picked up again after the marked date is old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   status   = 'Done',
      Datetime = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE Status   = 'TODO'
AND   ROWNUM   <= 1000;
```

However, you state in comments:

> Query will be run by another program based on other rules, and don't want to bring through 100K+ records so need to limit what is fetched each time while updating certain fields

An `UPDATE` statement does not send the rows to the client so you should not need to restrict the number of rows modified. If you want to modify them all then just modify them all using:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET   status   = 'Done',
      Datetime = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE Status   = 'TODO';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/My-IzhCK)